# Concatenate selected extensions to output

Tags: text-processing, cat

How to automatically concatenate selected extensions to output with same filename but different extension?

Input files (simplified):

```
File1.txt
File1.csv
File1.tsv
File2.txt
File2.csv
File2.gff
```

Action: concatenate *.txt and *.csv files into *.merged file (keeping the original filename, but different extension):

```
cat File1.txt File1.csv > File1.merged
cat File2.txt File2.csv > File2.merged
```

Desired output files:

```
File1.merged
File2.merged
```

Comment: Should only txt and csv files be merged? And only if both exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash:

```
txt_files=( *.txt )
for f in "${txt_files[@]}"; do 
    root=${f%%.*}
    [[ -f "$root.csv" ]] && cat "$root.txt" "$root.csv" > "$root.merged"
done
```

Comment: right, of course not.

Comment: You can suggest anything ;) But I disagree. I think that would harm readability at the expense of an insignificant performance gain. That would also break the OP's requirements IMO

Comment: Why the `txt_files` array and not simply `for f in *.txt; do ...`?

Comment: Good thought. I think I was in the middle of a half-baked idea.  Your idea is simpler

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner to do it:

`ls --ignore=*.tsv | grep File1 | xargs -d "\n" cat  >> file.merged`

or

`find . -not -name "*.tsv" -name "File1*" | xargs -d "\n" cat >> file.merged`

`ls` lists all of the files, but ignores the ones ending in .gff. `grep` sorts out everything else that isn't File1. The file name are then fed into the cat command, where `>>` appends them to file.merged

The only bad thing about this one is that you'd have to run it twice, once for File1 and for File2.

Comment: This would also concatenate `File1.tsv`, which is not wanted.

Comment: @Mark_R You were correct - I fixed that problem

Comment: Yes, this will be ok for this specific case, thanks. @glennjackman provided a more general answer